# X86 Fibonacci program

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

My assignment is to write a program that calculates first seven values of fibonacci number sequence. the formula given is:

```
Fib(1) = 1, Fib(2) = 1, Fib(n) = Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2)
```

I believe that is a function but I do not understand how to incorporate it into code. I need to place the values in EAX register. I am using MASM not that makes any difference. Any hints?

Comment: This is probably a homework assignment so I'll treat it as such.

Comment: The 7th fibonacci number when starting at 1 is 13, so just `mov eax, 13` and you're done. That, or you didn't give the full requirements.

Comment: I wrote up [a few versions for another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32661389/224132), including an unrolled-by-two version with minimal overhead for handling odd vs. even inputs, and a version that uses SSE vectors so it can do 64bit math on 32bit CPUs.  See the other answer on that question for some interesting Fibonacci math (e.g. a function to compute Fib(N) in O(log(N)) time).

Answer (score 7):

I suspect that this is an academic assignment so I'm only going to partially answer the question.

The fibonacci sequence is formally defined for non-negative integers as follows:

```
F(n) = n                   | n < 2
     = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2) | n >= 2
```

This gives:

```
  n | F(n)
  0 |   0
  1 |   1
  2 |   1
  3 |   2
  4 |   3
  5 |   5
  6 |   8
  7 |  13
etc etc...
```

You can do it with just a few registers, let's identify them:

- R<sub>n</sub> (the number of the requested fibonacci number)
- R<sub>f1</sub> (used to calculate fibonacci numbers)
- R<sub>f2</sub> (also used to calculate fibonacci numbers)
- R<sub>x</sub> (the register to hold the return value.  can overlap with any other register)

R<sub>n</sub> is passed as the argument to the function.  R<sub>f1</sub> shall start at 0, and R<sub>f2</sub> shall start at 1.

Here's what we do to get the answer, split up by routines:

**Begin**

1. Initialize R<sub>f1</sub> to 0.
2. Initialize R<sub>f2</sub> to 1.
3. Continue to Loop.

**Loop**

1. Subtract 2 from R<sub>n</sub>.
2. If R<sub>n</sub> is less than 0, jump to Finish.
3. Add R<sub>f2</sub> to R<sub>f1</sub>, storing the result in R<sub>f1</sub>.
4. Add R<sub>f1</sub> to R<sub>f2</sub>, storing the result in R<sub>f2</sub>.
5. Jump to Loop.

**Finish**

1. If R<sub>n</sub> AND 1 is false (implying that R<sub>n</sub> is even) jump to FinishEven.
2. Store R<sub>f1</sub> as the return value.
3. Return.

**FinishEven**

1. Store R<sub>f2</sub> as the return value.
2. Return.

Tracing through for R<sub>n</sub> = 5:

1. R<sub>f1</sub> = 0
2. R<sub>f2</sub> = 1
3. R<sub>n</sub> = R<sub>n</sub> - 2 // R<sub>n</sub> = 3
4. Test R<sub>n</sub> < 0 // false
5. R<sub>f1</sub> = R<sub>f1</sub> + R<sub>f2</sub> // R<sub>f1</sub> = 0 + 1 = 1
6. R<sub>f2</sub> = R<sub>f1</sub> + R<sub>f2</sub> // R<sub>f2</sub> = 1 + 1 = 2
7. Unconditional Jump to Loop
8. R<sub>n</sub> = R<sub>n</sub> - 2 // R<sub>n</sub> = 1
9. Test R<sub>n</sub> < 0 // false
10. R<sub>f1</sub> = R<sub>f1</sub> + R<sub>f2</sub> // R<sub>f1</sub> = 1 + 2 = 3
11. R<sub>f2</sub> = R<sub>f1</sub> + R<sub>f2</sub> // R<sub>f2</sub> = 3 + 2 = 5
12. Unconditional Jump to Loop
13. R<sub>n</sub> = R<sub>n</sub> - 2 // R<sub>n</sub> = -1
14. Test R<sub>n</sub> < 0 // true
15. Jump to Finish
16. Test R<sub>n</sub> & 1 // true
17. R<sub>x</sub> = R<sub>f2</sub> // 5

Our table shows that F(5) = 5, so this is correct.

Comment: Thanks, usefull but still not at my level. Maybe you could revise in laymens terms the formula?

Answer (score 1):

```
TITLE  Chapter 4 Exercise 6                (ch04_06.asm)

Comment !
Description: Write a program that uses a loop to calculate the first
seven values in the Fibonacci number sequence { 1,1,2,3,5,8,13 }.
Place each value in the EAX register and display it with a
call DumpRegs statement inside the loop.

Last update: 05/02/2002
!
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.code
main PROC
    mov   eax,1
    call  DumpRegs
    mov   ebx,0 ; initial setup
    mov   edx,1
    mov   ecx,6 ; count
L1:
    mov  eax,ebx    ; eax = ebx + edx
    add  eax,edx
    call DumpRegs   ; display eax
    mov  ebx,edx
    mov  edx,eax
    Loop L1

    exit
main ENDP
END main
```